# What does revoking/unlinking an auth provider in Firebase Authentication do?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have added Firebase Auth to my Android app and enabled Google sign in as well as added options to Link account, unlink account and revoke access to account. But I have a few questions how these features work with Firebase Auth.

1. When I revoke account access, in the Firebase Auth page, Google is **still** there as an Auth provider. I can still log in into my app with the account that I have just revoked. So what exactly does *Revoking Account Access* do?
2. When I unlink my Google account from Firebase Auth, Google is **not** there as the auth provider. *However*, I can still log in using the same Google account and have access to the same Firebase Auth account! Why does this happen even if the Google account is unlinked? Surely it should make a new account as it shouldn't have access to the old *unlinked* one? So what does *Unlinking* do if they can still log in using the *unlinked* Google account?

The only way I have found to make a new account in Firebase Auth using the same Google Sign in account is by deleting the old account. This is where my third question arises.

3. If my user has logged in using their Google Account to sign in to their **first** account in my app, and they would want to *unlink* their Google Account sign in from their **first** account, it in order to create a **second** account and link the same Google Account sign in to that **second** account. *However*, is this possible if the user **doesn't** want to delete their **first** account? Because this error happens `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: This credential is already associated with a different user account.`. So is it possible to fully remove the credential from the **first** account without deleting it?

Code for unlinking (From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#unlink-an-auth-provider-from-a-user-account):

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().unlink("google.com").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
                    }
                });
```

Code for revoking (From line 171 of: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/e8743a69ae3e21b66414fe9890b0dffaac20ff1d/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GoogleSignInActivity.java):

```
// Firebase sign out
        mAuth.signOut();

        // Google revoke access
        mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What does "revoke account access" mean here? What Firebase APIs do you call there?

Comment: I have added my code. I am using the methods provided by the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking and https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/e8743a69ae3e21b66414fe9890b0dffaac20ff1d/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GoogleSignInActivity.java